# Definition of a covering and how it applies to the following example

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $S= \{(x,y): x,y > 0\}$. The  collection $F$ of all circular disks with centers at $(x,x)$ and radius $x$, for $x>0$, is a covering of $S$. Then all disks such that $x$ is rational is considered a countable covering of $S$.

It seems to me that this can't be possible (perhaps this is one of those examples that shows  why geometric intuition is faulty). If we take the proposed countable covering, how could it be possible that we cover the very bottom left corner of $S$? Certainly if we were to pick a point, say $(\epsilon_0, \delta_0)$, we could find a disk that covered that point, but if we continued to divide $(\epsilon_0, \delta_0)$ by $2$ over and over again, we would constantly be "chasing" the point that needed to be covered -- never quite "catching up" to it.

I get that it's countable simply because we're dealing with rational numbers, but I don't understand how it could cover all of $S$.

Comment: Your objection is very vague. You should name a specific point that you think is not covered.

Comment: If $(x,y)$ in $S$ and y>x, then you just have to choose $q\in\mathbb Q$ close enough to $y$ so $(q-x)^2+(y-q)^2<q^2$.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Does that better clarify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle x,y\rangle\in S$. Without loss of generality $y\ge x$. For a rational number $q>0$ let $B_q$ be the open disk of radius $q$ with centre at $\langle q,q\rangle$. I claim that if $q$ is close enough to $y$, then $\langle x,y\rangle\in B_q$. This is obviously true if $y=q$, so let’s assume that $y$ is irrational, and let’s consider only rationals $q>y$. Suppose that $q>y$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\notin B_q$; then

$$\sqrt{(q-x)^2+(q-y)^2}\ge q\;,$$

i.e.,

$$(q-x)^2+(q-y)^2\ge q^2\;,$$

or $$(q-y)^2\ge q^2-(q-x)^2=2qx-x^2>2xy-x^2\ge x^2\;.$$

Thus, we need only choose a rational $q\in(y,y+x)$ to ensure that $(q-y)^2<x^2$ and hence that $$\sqrt{(q-x)^2+(q-y)^2}<q$$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\in B_q$.

Answer (score 0):

**This is true:**

Firstly, you must be clear what's meaning of covering $S$. All disks such that $x$ is rational is a countable covering of $S$ which means that $$S=\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb Q} B_x$$, where $B_x$ is   circular disks with centers at $(x,x)$ and raduis $x$. Only need you to prove is just picking any point of $S$, then it belongs $\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb Q} B_x$. That is all. Clearly, it is true just as Brain did. Hope it be helpful for you.